# cast list of anonymous type to list of object

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I am trying to create a anonymous list which can hold any `data type` with `intellisense` support but without creating a `class`.

So I found below solution to use anonymous type.

```
  var list = new[]
  { 
     new { Number = 10, Name = "Smith" },
     new { Number = 10, Name = "John" } 
  }.ToList();

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
  }
```

But what if I want a method which returns above anonymous type.

```
public List<object> GetData()
{

    var list = new[]
    {
        new { Number = 10, Name = "Smith" },
        new { Number = 10, Name = "John" }
    }.ToList();

    return list;
```

}

**Compile Time Error:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Is it possible to cast list of anonymous type to list of object with intellisense support ?

**Update:**

The reason we don't want to create a type , because we just want to do some data manipulation using the anonymous type and populate some other objects that's all.

Comment: Is tuple an option here?

Comment: "Is it possible to cast list of anonymous type to list of object with intellisense support ?" Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a class? An anonymous type is still a class, you just don't know it's name.

Comment: @DragandDrop , We tried using `Tuple` but it doesn't give readability because we need to access property as `Item1` , `Item2` so forth...

Comment: I suspect just creating a type will be the shortest/cleanest path to a solution here.  Why all the effort to avoid that?

Comment: Anonymous types aren't meant to be used outside of a generic or local context, so no. You will either have to return `object`, `dynamic` or one of the tuple types or similar, but you cannot return anonymous types with intellisense. For that we already have the correct solution, create a proper named type.

Comment: Tuples in new C# compiler supports naming, but this is a trick, it quickly falls apart. Again, the correct way to do this is to use a proper named type.

Comment: @DavidG, @David , Currently we are not planning to create a `type` , we are trying to achieve this without a `type`.

Comment: @stom: Which again begs the question... *why*?  You're trying to achieve type-safety without using types?  This seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: Yes, we know you're not going to create a type, but you haven't said why that is the case. If you need to expose data as part of an API of any sort, then you need a type.

Comment: Return `dynamic` then and hope for the best. It won't give you intellisense but it will allow you to easily get to the members inside.

Comment: @stom : but when you are doing new {} you are in fact creating a new type. Just that it is Anonymous

Comment: What if you use .ToList<object>();

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen `dynamic` have no intellisense support....

Comment: @Obfuscate : you will not have the iintellisense support

Comment: You cannot get intellisense support outside of the method without naming the type.

Comment: To get your existing code to compile, use `.OfType<object>().ToList()` or its shorthand: `.ToList<object>()`. This still won't give you intellisense outside of the method.

Comment: I don't understand your aversion to creating a type. You're simply making your life harder. All the compiler is doing when it sees an anonymous type is creating a new type at compile time, except you can't work with it easily.

Comment: If you can use c# 7 features - you can use named tuples.

Comment: Named tuples, or create a type, and almost everyone here is suggesting the latter (for good reason!)

Comment: No. This isn't possible. 

You can return a `List<object>` or a `List<dynamic>`, but you will have no intellisense support outside the method where the anonymous type was created.

Comment: You have spent more energy and time arguing with people here than it would've taken you to create the type, which is still the only correct answer.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , you are correct , but I was curious to know if its possible ,   but why I don't know I get down votes , I am sorry if I asked unnecessary question.

Comment: It is possible for me to go stand in a doorway and repeatedly slam the door in my own face, but whether it makes good sense for me to do that is another matter. *Just create the type.*

Comment: @Trioj I understand `creating a type` is the best way to go, but our requirement was without creating a type , I have given update on the post explaining why. so if in future required we will create a type. Thanks to all for suggestions, appreciate.

Comment: @stom Understood, but here are my thoughts for the record: the requirement to not create a type is a problem and should have been opposed by the engineering team, IMO. Your post explains that you have a requirement but does not explain why the requirement makes any sense at all. I believe that if your product team requires something inane, it's on engineering to push back on that and suggest a better design and explain why it is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the ways possible:

1. Return a `List<object>`, which means you have no intellisense on the receiving end
2. Return a `List<dynamic>`, which means you have no intellisense on the receiving end, but perhaps easier to access members you know are there than through reflection
3. Return a `List<T>` but then you will have to provide an example of how `T` is supposed to look and this won't be any more safe at runtime than `dynamic` is
4. Return a tuple of the new type that came with C# 7

Point 1 and 2 can be easily solved by just ensuring the list is of that type:

```
...
}.ToList<object>();
```

Point 3 is a hack but I'll post it below.

Point 4 can be solved with this syntax:

```
public List<(int Number, string Name)> GetData()
{

    var list = new[]
    {
        (Number: 10, Name: "Smith"),
        (Number: 10, Name: "John")
    }.ToList();

    return list;
}
```

This will give you intellisense for a while but the naming of the properties is a hack by the compiler and if you start passing these values around they will easily fall back to `.Item1` and `.Item2`.

---

To cast an object to a specific type you can use a hack which only works in the same assembly that the anonymous object was created in, and that is that multiple anonymous types used around in your code, which has the same properties, in the same order, with the same property types, all end up being the same anonymous type.

You can thus cast an `object` to a specific anonymous type with this hackish code:

```
public T AnonymousCast<T>(object value, T example) => (T)value;
public IEnumerable<T> AnonymousCastAll<T>(IEnumerable<object> collection, T example) => collection.OfType<T>();
```

You would use it in your case like this:

```
var d = AnonymousCast(GetData()[0], new { Number = 0, Name = "" });
```

This is no more safe than using `dynamic` as there is no guarantee the object returned from `GetData` *actually* is of that anonymous type.

In short, use a named type.

Comment: Can I pass `GetData()` instead of `GetData()[0]` ?

Comment: Added `AnonymousCastAll` but **do not use these!** You might as well just use `dynamic`. I can easily just do `AnonymousCast(o, new { Foo = 42, Bar = 17 })` and it will compile but it won't run. You will get intellisense for what you ask for intellisense for, not for what the objects actually provide.

Comment: Guess This [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/477519/Return-Anonymous-type) has same info you posted. Thank you so much for the efforts.

Comment: Apparently I have to upgrade to C# 7 or above :(